# sass / scss - create class shortcuts

Tags: sass

While doing some css I came up with the idea of combining multiple classes into one. The reason is, to use short class names which could probably already be in use.

Assume the following:

```
.f-box-cell {
  flex : 1 1 auto;

  // colors
  &.red   { background-color: red; }
  &.green { background-color: green; }
  ...

  // sizes
  &.b25 { flex-basis: 25%; }
  &.b50 { flex-basis: 50%; }
  ...

  // other options
  ...
}
```

Instead of doing ...

```
<div class="f-box-cell">
<div class="f-box-cell red">
<div class="f-box-cell b25">
<div class="f-box-cell red b25">
```

... I want do have something like ...

```
<div class="f-box-cell">
<div class="f-box-cell-red">
<div class="f-box-cell-b25">
<div class="f-box-cell-red-b25">
```

... with the same effect as the normal class listings.

Obviously, the more "subclasses" are added the more combinations would exist. So I'm interessted - if possible - in creating all these combinations automatically. Completely awesome would be, if the position of the "classes" inside the "combined class" would not matter.

Therefore my 2 main questions are:

1. Is there a way to achieve something like this with sass / scss?
2. Is the idea completely stupid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have all your classes prefixed and don't mind adding two classes (`class="f-box-cell f-box-cell-red"`), then you can just use the ampersand multiple times:

```
.f-box-cell {
   flex : 1 1 auto;

   // colors
   & &-red   { background-color: red; }
   & &-green { background-color: green; }
   ...

   // sizes
   & &-b25 { flex-basis: 25%; }
   & &-b50 { flex-basis: 50%; }
   ...

   // other options
   ...
}
```

If you only want to use the most specific class, which should inherit from the base one, you can use the [`@extend` rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend):

```
.f-box-cell {
   flex : 1 1 auto;

   // colors
   &-red   { @extend .f-box-cell; background-color: red; }
   &-green { @extend .f-box-cell; background-color: green; }
   ...

   // sizes
   &-b25 { @extend .f-box-cell; flex-basis: 25%; }
   &-b50 { @extend .f-box-cell; flex-basis: 50%; }
   ...

   // other options
   ...
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.f-box-cell,
.f-box-cell-b50,
.f-box-cell-b25,
.f-box-cell-green,
.f-box-cell-red {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.f-box-cell-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.f-box-cell-green {
  background-color: green;
}

.f-box-cell-b25 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.f-box-cell-b50 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Not completely what I'm looking for, but thank you for the cool hint with the double ampersand and @ extend. I did not know that before.